# How to count the number of words with more than 3 same letters

Tags: c

My program counts the number of words with 3 letters but I need to count the words with 3 identical letters. I am trying to write a program that counts the number of words that have more than three letters. The program has to end when a period is entered. My code works, but it scores all words with 3 letters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int cont = 0, counterLargerThanThree = 0;

    printf("Enter a phrase that ends with a period:\n");

    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != ' ' && c != '.') {
            ++cont;
        } else {
            if (cont == 3) {
                counterLargerThanThree++;
            }
            cont = 0;
        }
    } while (c != '.');

    printf("%i \n", counterLargerThanThree);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you want to know if all 3 letters are the same you will have to remember the first letter and then check if the following 2 letters have the same character. I think you will be able to solve this by yourself.

Comment: *" i need to count the words with 3 same leters."* - what does that *mean* ? Are you trying to count the number of words that share at least three common letters *between words*  (e.g. "duck" and "truck") ? Or are you trying to count words where each word has at least three occurrences of the same letter (e.g. "lollapalooza"), thereby making its 'count' status completely independent of other words? Or... just words with at least three letters (e.g. "one", "two", but not "at" or "I"). This is the part where *examples* of expected input and output are *important*.

Comment: Are you looking for words containing three letters, or three identical letters in a row, or one letter appearing three times at any point? The first one is a lot simpler

Comment: `[0, 3]` 4 counts, which will fit in 2 bits, ASCII 26 letters, you need 52 (64) bits to solve this in `O(n)`. However, if your words are short, (>~50?) , _st_ the number is low, I think that having one `int` for each count is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

All you've to do is modify the logic of incrementing your result.

- When you're taking a character other than `space` and `.`, that means, when the condition `if (c != ' ' && c != '.')` is `true`, increment frequency of the character
- In other case, that means when the above condition is `false`, check if the last word you've taken as input has `3` same characters. If it has then increment your result.

Sample code:

```
int main()
{
    char c;

    int wordWithThreeSameLetter = 0;
    int frequency[26];  // assuming there'll be only small letters in input

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        frequency[i] = 0;   // initializing the count of every character
    }

    printf("Enter a phrase that ends with a period:\n");

    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c != ' ' && c != '.')
        {
            frequency[c - 'a']++;    // incrementing count of the character
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                if(frequency[i] == 3) wordWithThreeSameLetter++;    // counting word with 3 same letter

                frequency[i] = 0;   // initializing the count for future word
            }
        }
    }
    while (c != '.');

    printf("%i \n", wordWithThreeSameLetter);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
a
b
c
 
e
f
e
g
e
 
x
y
y
o
y
.
```

Output: 2

Input:

```
a
b
c
 
d
e
e
f
.
```

Output: 0

N.B. -

- As you haven't mentioned specifically about input format, I assumed there'll be only `small letter character` , `space` and `.` in input. So above code will work only for such input.

Comment: `frequency[c - 'a']++;` is very delicate; if you type a capital or forget a period, the number is negative and undefined behaviour. At least put a check?